# Argument of type 'Image' is not iterable

Tags: python-3.x

I need to open a directory using the mugshot["path"] which has jpg images in it. Once I find the images I resize them and copy them using copyfile. The comments I added are what is printed from the the print method. Here is my code.

```
        for mugshot in self.mugshots:
                print("mugshot is: ", mugshot) # prints {'path': '/leds/files/2021/1000000580', 'name': 'IN202100005_R.jpg'}

                try:
                    if self.mugshots_folder:
                        path = copyfile.join(self.afis_export_connection_string, self.mugshots_folder, mugshot["name"])
                    else:
                        path = copyfile.join(G.global_settings[(agenciesid, "afis_mugshot_export_connection_string")],
                                             mugshot["name"])
                    try:
                        with open(mugshot["path"], 'rb') as mugshot1:
                            im = Image.open(mugshot1)
                            print("im is=", im) # im is= <PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=2560x1080 at 0x7F0218F7C668>
                            print("im type is=", type(im)) # im type is= <class 'PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile'>
                            newsize = (480, 600)
                            im1 = im.resize(newsize)
                            print("im1 after resize is: ", im1) #im1 after resize is:  <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=480x600 at 0x7F0218F74C18>
                            temp = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
                            print("temp is: ", temp) #temp is:  <_io.BufferedRandom name=14>
                            im1.save(temp, format="JPEG")
                            print("im1.save ran") #im1.save ran
                            temp.seek(0)

                            copyfile.copyfile(im1, path) # params are (source, destination)
                            print("copyfile.copyfile ran") #this doesn't get printed
                            temp.close()

                    except Exception as e:
                        print("exception occurred ", e)
```

I get "exception occurred  argument of type 'Image' is not iterable". Is there another approach I can use to go through all the paths of my mugshots? Or is there something else wrong with my code?

Comment: what is `copyfile.copyfile`? do you perhaps mean `shutil.copyfile`?

Answer (score 0):

So I initially thought copyfile.copyfile was shutil.copyfile but this wasn't the case. The copyfile here was actually another custom function created which I didn't find out til later today. This function took in special characters for pathing which caused other issues. Working code after some minor changes

```
with open(mugshot["path"], 'rb') as mugshot_to_resize:
                        img = Image.open(mugshot_to_resize)
                        new_size = (480, 600)
                        image_resize = img.resize(new_size)
                        temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
                        image_resize.save(temp, format="JPEG")
                        temp.seek(0)
                        copyfile.copyfile(temp.name, path)
                        temp.close()
```